# Get mailbox information in Powershell for Office 365

Tags: powershell, office365

Is it possible to get username, Full name, mailbox size, mailbox quota in MB, total size of space available for all mailboxes in PowerShell for Exchange 365?

So far I got:

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-Object DisplayName,StorageLimitStatus,TotalItemSize
```

Thanks!